# std::locale to split string by specific char without ignoring it

Tags: c++, string, c++11, stream

I want to split a string by specific chars without ignoring them.

For example if I have the string:

> "some_tag = some_value"

I can use this locale(copied/adapted from cppreference) to split it into tokens:

```
struct split_by_equal : std::ctype<char>
{
    static const mask* make_table()
    {
        static std::vector<mask> v(classic_table(), classic_table() + table_size);
        v['='] |=  space;
        return &v[0];
    }

    split_by_equal() : ctype(make_table()){}
};

...

std::stringstream stream("some_tag = some_value");
stream.imbue(std::locale(std::locale::classic(), new split_by_equal));

std::string token;
while(stream>>token)
{
    std::cout<<token<<std::endl;
}
```

This works, except I can't know if '=' was there once, multiple times or it was missing. To know this information is very important to validate the input string.

Is it possible to make the parsing stop at the character without extracting it from the stream?

PS: I want to use std::locale because the real problem is not as simple as splitting a string using only '=' as separator:)

EDIT:

I would like to be able to parse in the same way following strings:

```
"some_tag=some_value"
"some_tag
=
some_value"
"some_tag = some_value"
```

and be able to report the error for the next ones:

```
"some_tag some_value"
"some_tag == some_value"
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update**: My last example didn't taken into account the other cases you wanted to handle. I've tested all of them and they seem to work with this example:

```c++
template<char c>
std::istream& strip_until(std::istream& is)
{
    auto& ctype = std::use_facet<std::ctype<char>>(is.getloc());
    int val = std::char_traits<char>::to_int_type(c);
    bool b;

    while ((b = ctype.is(ctype.space, is.peek())) && is.peek() != val)
        is.ignore();

    if (!b && is.peek() != val)
        is.setstate(std::ios_base::failbit);

    return is;
}

...

while (stream >> token >> strip_until<'='>)
{
    // stream.peek() is '='
}
```

Comment: I have a problem with "some_tag=some_value". This will be read as one string without the facet.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) with the custom delimiter argument, followed by a call (or more) with the default `'\n'`. Unless you share with us the full problem, this is still the simplest and most effective solution.

Then you can check for any case you wish to handle. It will be difficult though to handle something like this:

```
some_tag
=
some_tag = some_value
```

Which seems like a case you might want to handle, although this is very dependent on what you want to parse.